# Kafka python Consumer group session timed out

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, producer-consumer, confluent-platform

I use confluent-kafka v1.3.0 and I have following problem with consumer group session timeout. 
My config looks like:

```
c['KAFKA'] = {
    'bootstrap.servers': 'host.docker.internal:9104',
    'consumer': {
        'group.id': 'consumer',
        'enable.auto.commit': True,
        'default.topic.config': {
            'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest
        },
        'heartbeat.interval.ms': 100000,
        'max.poll.interval.ms': 300000,
        'session.timeout.ms': 100000
    },
}
```

and logic in code like:

```
consumer.subscribe('database_changes')

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=500) as executor:
    while True:
        msg = consumer.poll(100)
        if msg is not None:
            executor.submit(process_message, msg)
```

Code in function process message waits a few ms because it's really simple logic. Everything works good but every moment I got this error:

```
{"asctime":"2020-04-27 08:42:25,759","levelname":"WARNING","name":"services.kafka","message":"SESSTMOUT [rdkafka#consumer-2] [thrd:main]: Consumer group session timed out (in join-state started) after 30131 ms without a successful response from the group coordinator (broker 0, last error was Success): revoking assignment and rejoining group"}
```

these rebalacing greatly hampers the whole process.

Does anyone have an idea of what can be wrongly set? I suspect a not working heartbeat, but I don't know how it verify or better fix.

Thanks

Comment: just to share information, I do have the same issue using the default settings for heart-beat and session.timeout (6000) and I am using confluent-kafka 1.4.2.

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As per the confluent kafka docs, the heartbeat.interval.ms should be set no higher than 1/3 of session.timeout.ms. Since after the sessions.timeout.ms value, the consumer is assumed dead, it is recommended to wait atleast three heartbeats to assume that.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#heartbeat.interval.ms